# I am getting this error and I cant solve it error:-( _this.state.tokenFarm.methods.stakeTokens is not a function)and whole code is given below ASAP

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

// ALL CODE WITH INITIALIZATION OF CONTRACTS ARE GIVEN HERE PLAESE HELP ME ASAP

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DaiToken from '../abis/DaiToken.json'
import DappToken from '../abis/DappToken.json'
import TokenFarm from '../abis/TokenFarm.json'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import './App.css'
import Main from './Main'

class App extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.loadWeb3()
    await this.loadBlockchainData()
  }

  async loadBlockchainData() {
    const web3 = window.web3
    if (!web3) {
      return window.alert('Please install MetaMask or use a web3-enabled browser to access this dApp.')
    }

    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    this.setState({ account: accounts[0] })

    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()

    // Load DaiToken
    const daiTokenData = DaiToken.networks[networkId]
    if (daiTokenData) {
      const daiToken = new web3.eth.Contract(DaiToken.abi, daiTokenData.address)
      this.setState({ daiToken })
      let daiTokenBalance = await daiToken.methods.balanceOf(this.state.account).call()
      this.setState({ daiTokenBalance: daiTokenBalance.toString() })
    } else {
      window.alert('DaiToken contract not deployed to detected network')
    }

    // Load DappToken
    const dappTokenData = DappToken.networks[networkId]
    if (dappTokenData) {
      const dappToken = new web3.eth.Contract(DappToken.abi, dappTokenData.address)
      this.setState({ dappToken })
      let dappTokenBalance = await dappToken.methods.balanceOf(this.state.account).call()
      this.setState({ dappTokenBalance: dappTokenBalance.toString() })
    } else {
      window.alert('DappToken contract not deployed to detected network.')
    }

    // Load TokenFarm
    const tokenFarmData = TokenFarm.networks[networkId]
    if (tokenFarmData) {
      const tokenFarm = new web3.eth.Contract(TokenFarm.abi, tokenFarmData.address)
      this.setState({ tokenFarm })
      let stakingBalance = await tokenFarm.methods.stakingBalance(this.state.account).call()
      this.setState({ stakingBalance: stakingBalance.toString() })
    } else {
      window.alert('TokenFarm contract not deployed to detected network.')
    }

    this.setState({ loading: false })
  }

  async loadWeb3() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
      await window.ethereum.enable()
    } else if (window.web3) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
    } else {
      window.alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    }
  }

  stakeTokens = async (amount) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    await this.state.daiToken.methods.approve(this.state.tokenFarm._address, amount).send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', async (hash) => {
      await this.state.tokenFarm.methods.stakeTokens(amount).send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false })
      })
    })
  }
  unstakeTokens = (amount) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    this.state.tokenFarm.methods.unstakeTokens().send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    })
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      account: '0x0',
      daiToken: {},
      dappToken: {},
      tokenFarm: {},
      daiTokenBalance: '0',
      dappTokenBalance: '0',
      stakingBalance: '0',
      loading: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    let content
    if(this.state.loading){
      content = <p id="loader" className='text-center'>loading...</p>
    }else{
      content = <Main
      daiTokenBalance={this.state.daiTokenBalance}
      dappTokenBalance={this.state.dappTokenBalance}
      stakingBalance={this.state.stakingBalance}
      stakeTokens={this.stakeTokens}
      unstakeTokens={this.unstakeTokens}
      />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar account={this.state.account} />
        <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
          <div className="row">
            <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 ml-auto mr-auto" style={{ maxWidth: '600px' }}>
              <div className="content mr-auto ml-auto">
                <a
                  href="http://www.dappuniversity.com/bootcamp"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                </a>

                {content}

              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the section in which i am getting error

```
stakeTokens = async (amount) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    await this.state.daiToken.methods.approve(this.state.tokenFarm._address, amount).send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', async (hash) => {
      await this.state.tokenFarm.methods.stakeTokens(amount).send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false })
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: I don't know how to ask proper question however anyone please contact me on this email please help me ASAP. devangt101003@gmail.com on this email ID,                             Thank you

Comment: The contracts are missing. It could be that the functions are defined in the contracts, the contract abi is wrong, the contract address is wrong, it is connected to the wrong network, etc.